# What is with this MySQL syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been through my 5.1.73 MySQL manual and I just can't find the syntax error that MySQL is giving me when I try to POST/GET something:

```
mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO serial (name, company, algo, country, notes) VALUES ('.$_GET['name'].','.$_GET['company'].','.$_GET['algo'].','.$_GET['country'].','.$_GET['notes'].')');
```

MySQL Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FCINGZ000***,Unknown,Thanks)' at line 1

Comment: Please post the error message and search for SQL Injection. You're probably missing quite a few single-quotes (`'`) around your string values.

Comment: @ccKep You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FCINGZ000***,Unknown,Thanks)' at line 1

Comment: Using a prepared statement will fix this (you are missing quotes around the string values) it will also fix the huge SQL Injection vulnerability you have, See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: As an aside, be aware that serial is considered a keyword in MySQL- though it's not reserved as such.

Comment: And see prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the `$_GET` values to a variable to prevent syntax errors. Also, prevent MySQL Injection using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['name']);
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['company']);
$algo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['algo']);
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['country']);
$notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['notes']);

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO serial (name, company, algo, country, notes) VALUES ('$name', '$company', '$algo', '$country', '$notes')");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but with that I get a PHP parse error.

Comment: Whoops I forgot to paste it in!:)
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/html/SN/postdata.php on line 11

Comment: @Kirsty Updated post, it should work now

Comment: This doesn't prevent injection. See prepared statements

Comment: Use a prepared statement, its what they are for.